# LINQ inner join betwenn Enumerable and DB Table

Tags: .net, linq, inner-join, enumerable, dbtable

I'm trying to determine which records to delete from a database when a user submits a form.
The page has two CheckBoxList one representing the records before modification and one after.

I can easily get the selected values that need to be deleted like this...

```
//get the items not selected that were selected before
var oldSelectedItems = from oItem in oldChklSpecialNeeds.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                       where !(from nItem in newChklSpecialNeeds.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                               where nItem.Selected
                               select nItem.Value).Contains(oItem.Value)
                           && oItem.Selected
                       select oItem.Value;
```

now I am trying to do something like this but it isn't allowing it...

```
var itemsToDelete = from specialNeed in db.SpecialNeeds
                           join oldSelectedItem in oldSelectedItems on specialNeed.SpecialNeedsTypeCd equals oldSelectedItem.Value
                           where specialNeed.CustomerId == customerId
```

I can easily just use a foreach loop and a .DeleteOnSubmit() for each item but I'm thinking there is a way use functionality of LINQ and pass the whole query result of an inner join to .DeleteAllOnSubmit()

```
//like so
db.SpecialNeeds.DeleteAllOnSubmit(itemsToDelete);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local collections can be used in LINQ to SQL with the Contains() method. You can try changing the *join* clause into a *where* with Contains():

```
var itemsToDelete = from specialNeed in db.SpecialNeeds
                    where oldSelectedItems.Contains(specialNeed.SpecialNeedsTypeCd)
                       && specialNeed.CustomerId == customerId
                    select ...;
```

Comment: .Contains is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?  Is it a type mismatch between SpecialNeedsTypeCd and oldSelectedItem.Value?  Have you just omitted the select in the second Linq statement in this post or is that the problem?